# Start service from systemd with ubuntu

Tags: 18.04, bash, scripts

I'm trying to launch a .jar file (Spring Boot 1.4.0) through systemd and it's returning error exit code 126

Code that is in the system folder

```
/etc/systemd/system/Painel.service
[Unit] Description=Iniciar painel After=syslog.target

[Service] User=lrv ExecStart=/bin/bash sudo java -jar /home/lrv/painelWeb-20.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar $

SuccessExitStatus=143 TimeoutStopSec=10 Restart=on-failure RestartSec=5

[Install] WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Before the error exite code 127 was displayed, but I made some changes to the command and now it has error 126, the main ones I made were in the $PATH and I added Java

```
echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/usr/bin/java:/usr/bin/javac:/home/lrv/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0/bin
```

From what I saw the error 126, it recognizes the command, but it doesn't execute different from 127 that doesn't even recognize it and that's why in ExecStart I added sudo

I also gave the script permission with sudo chmod +x and on the file (jar file) I want to start with  Ubuntu

Logs
journalctl -u Painel.service -l -n 50

```
Painel.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Painel.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Painel.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 17.
Stopped Iniciar painel.
Started Iniciar painel.
 /usr/bin/sudo: /usr/bin/sudo: unable to run the binary file
 Painel.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=126/n/a
 Painel.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
 Painel.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
 Painel.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 18.
 Stopped Iniciar painel.
 Started Iniciar painel.
 /usr/bin/sudo: /usr/bin/sudo: unable to run the binary file
 Painel.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=126/n/a
 Painel.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
 Painel.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
 Painel.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 19.
 Stopped Iniciar painel.
 Started Iniciar painel.
 /usr/bin/sudo: /usr/bin/sudo: unable to run the binary file
 Painel.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=126/n/a
 Painel.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
 Painel.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
 Painel.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 20.
 Stopped Iniciar painel.
 Started Iniciar painel.
 /usr/bin/sudo: /usr/bin/sudo: unable to run the binary file
 Painel.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=126/n/a
 Painel.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
 Painel.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
 Painel.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 21.
 Stopped Iniciar painel.
 Started Iniciar painel.
/usr/bin/sudo: /usr/bin/sudo: unable to run the binary file
Painel.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=126/n/a
Painel.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Comment: I think your copy/paste failed.  We need the full output of your logs - `journalctl -u Painel.service -l -n 50` to get the journal error logs, and then provide us the information about what it says during runtime execution and why it fails.  Error "126" or "127" is infinitely vague and will not help debugging - actual error output will help.

Comment: A updated my post with the Painel.service logs (journalctl -u Painel.service -l -n 50)

Answer (score 0):

You are not able to safely use `sudo` in SystemD units.  Which is one of the reasons you get the error "unable to run the binary file" errors in the logs.

Instead of using `sudo` in your service file definitions, you need to define the `User` and `Group` to run your service under, in order to make it execute with superuser privs.

Add `User=root` and `Group=root` to your Service section.  Remove `sudo` from your `ExecStart` line.  Save the file then run `sudo systemctl daemon-reload` to refresh the service file data SystemD is aware of.

Then start your service.

Comment: I added User=root and Group=root before ExectStart and run sudo systemctl daemon-reload, but still get a message error

/usr/bin/java: /usr/bin/java: unable to run the binary file
when i enter this path there is no java file

i will reinstall java